# Css edits and Adding graphic controls to sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to change the look and feel of my sharePoint site, make some CSS edits and want to add few graphic controls on the left navigation. I found many ways of doing it but it breaks my master page and degrades the version. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Mate, what you're asking for fills books. Break it down into smaller parts. What have you tried?

Comment: Ok, so i need to add a whole new navigation panel under quick launch, i tried adding a class in the html copy of master page, but unable to to do. How do i implement this?